# そう "seem" used for hearing

Tags: grammar

In a book someone hears a woman voice and says:

> 心配そうな、お母さんの声

As far as I know, `そう(な)` is to say something seems **based on visual information**, and my grammars agree with this: things like `おいしそうなケーキ`. If linked to something you heard, `そう` is used to report what you said/heard, like `明日だそうだった`, "I heard it's tomorrow".

Given the context, it seems to me that `そう` is the first meaning, since the character isn't reporting something she heard.

Is that `そう` the first meaning? If so, is that use wrong/unusual?

Comment: The key is to think of senそうry information in general, not only visual

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use そう, your judgement can be based on any of your five senses:

- [after seeing a dish] おいしそう。
- [after hearing about a dish over a phone] おいしそう。
- [after lifting a box up] 中に何か入ってそう。
- [after smelling a dish] 腐ってそう。
- [after tasting a dish] ワサビが入ってそう。

そう for hearsay has nothing to do with this because it must follow a dictionary form of a verb/adjective. "I heard [he] is worried" is 心配**だ**そうだ.